# "Многоходовочка" українською?

Tags: переклад, калька, суфікси

В ґуґлі видача на запит "багатоходівка" — 5,800 результатів. Хоча не впевнений щодо цього слова. В словниках його наче нема. І навіть якщо припустити, що це правильний еквівалент, то наскільки правильно буде говорити "багатоходовочка"? Що тут робиться з суфіксами?

Чи притаманне таке словотворення українській мові — "-овочка"? Чи не могли б ви детальніше пояснити, що з чим тут чергується і з яких суфіксів складається ця частина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Багатоходівка, багатоходівочка

[«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) містять слово ***багатоході́вка***. Знаходить декілька траплянь цього слова й [корпус «ГРАК»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac5&queryselector=lemmarow&lemma=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> <sub>Це своєрідне колективного авторства фентезі з розбудованими й вишуканими багатоходівками, непролазними хащами макро- і мікрорівневих стосунків між угрупованнями, «командами» та окремими «лідерами», не видимими простому смертному оку лабіринтами й комбінаціями. // Юрій Андрухович «Гра у висер», 2018.</sub>
>
> <sub>Але, вже перебуваючи в Петербурзі, Скоропадський довідався про те, що російська влада за його спиною перепризначила новгород-сіверського сотника, задіявши при цьому таку собі «багатоходівку»: поставила Семена Соболевського сотником у Погар, а «прежнего» погарського сотника Семена Галецького перевела сотником до Новгород-Сіверського. // Віктор Горобець «Світанок української держави раннього Нового часу. Влада, соціум, люди, порядки, традиції», 2017.</sub>
>
> <sub>Сам Г. дав тому достатній привід — і народ краще (точніше — гірше) сприйме історію божевільного вбивці, Ц.-молодшого, ніж заплутану і надто складну багатоходівку із перснями (в якій, зізнатися, я і сам не все розумію, хоча наша тимчасова співпраця із людьми Барабанщика прояснила деякі її темні місця, про що йтиметься нижче). //  Володимир Арєнєв «Магус», 2007.</sub>
>
> <sub>І в підсумку — мали би об'єднаний гетьманат і політичного лідера, якому можна було б домовлятися вже і з Варшавою, і з Москвою. — Така хитра багатоходівка. // Дмитро Шурхало під час інтерв'ю «350-річчя Андрусівської угоди: як Україну розділили вздовж Дніпра?» з Тарасом Чухлібом і Владиславом Яценком.</sub>
>
> <sub>Всяка правда — результат такої заплутаної багатоходівки, зі стількома ходами прихованими, що простій людині повік у тому не розібратися. // Оксана Забужко «Музей покинутих секретів», 2009.</sub>
>
> <sub>А в тому, що суд вона програє, сумнівів практично не було: ніхто би не став зажиратися з упливовою ефемкою через якусь пєвіцу ртом, не маючи готової багатоходівки. // Оксана Форостина «Duty free», 2011.</sub>

Зменшувальний суфікс (чи комбінація двох суфіксів?) *-очк-* цілком притаманний українській мові: часточка, жіночка, панночка, вісточка, гілочка тощо. Єдине що — в такому випадку, по-моєму, мало б бути радше ***багатоходівочка***, а не *багатоходовочка* (як от: гвинтівка — гвинтівочка, мандрівка — мандрівочка, верхівка — верхівочка).

#### Багатокроківка, багатокроківочка

А ще в мережі вживають «багатокроківка» і «багатокроківочка». Щоправда, у словниках цих слів немає. У пресі я бачу одне трапляння багатокроківки — у назві статті «АнтиНАБУшна багатокроківка» в «Українській правді» й наразі жодного трапляння багатокроківочки (хоча загалом у мережі багатокроківочка трапляється навіть частіше за багатокроківку).

Щодо доречності коренів -крок- і -хід- мені важко сказати однозначно. З одного боку, тут є натяк на гру (зокрема шахи), а в іграх це називається [хід](http://sum.in.ua/s/khid) (багатокроківочка є радше відповідником неіснуючого російського слова «многошаговочка», ніж «многоходовочка»; і польською це називається [«wielochodówka»](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wielochod%C3%B3wka), а не «wielokrokówka»). З іншого, я не бачу категоричних причин, через які це слово обов'язково асоціювати саме з багатоходовою шаховою задачею, а не, наприклад, з багатокроковим планом/стратегією/тактикою.

У будь-якому разі, за словниками й частотою практичного вжитку наразі перевагу мають *багатоходівка* й *багатоходівочка*.

Comment: Корпус "Грак" - це щось на кшталт Google Books Ngram Viewer'а? Якось я думав, що не вистачає чогось подібного для українського літературного середовища.

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy, гм, а я не знав раніше про Google Books Ngram Viewer, дякую. Я б сказав, що це дещо більше (не за кількістю охоплених текстів, звісно, а за функціональністю) — якщо я правильно зрозумів (поглянув зараз швидко, може, чогось не помітив), Google Books Ngram Viewer лише будує графіки, а ГРАК дозволяє отримувати різні види інформації й задавати складніші запити (наприклад, «будь-яка форма леми _нести_ за якою йде іменник в орудному відмінку» на CQL). Ось на Вікіпедії стаття з посиланням: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Генеральний_регіонально_анотований_корпус_української_мови.

Comment: @OleksiyPlotnyts'kyy, а, перепрошую, помітив, що Google Books Ngram Viewer дозволяє й raw data завантажувати. («ГРАК» — не єдиний корпус текстів українською мовою, є й інші, але я б сказав, що цей наразі найповніший за обсягом текстів і функціональністю.)

Comment: дякую за посилання. Тут ось можна детальніше про advanced usage почитати: https://books.google.com/ngrams/info

Comment: Я б перекладав як "ланцюжанка" :)